# Is This a Memory Crash? NSZombies doesn't catch it

Tags: ios, memory

Is this **definitely** a memory crash, or should I be looking for something else?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x81093cd0
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33563f78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x34d6b92c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 408
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35919a2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35919692 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 358
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35918268 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3589b49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3589b366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
7   GraphicsServices                0x33636432 GSEventRunModal + 130
8   UIKit                           0x33073cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
```

Using the profiler, live bytes are well under 10MB at all times, and when memory warns happen I'm back to 3MB or below.

This statement returns YES, so I assume I have zombies enabled:

```
getenv("NSZombieEnabled") || getenv("NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled")
```

When I'm running from Xcode, the app crashes without Xcode even being aware (after some arbitrary number of memory warns).

Any suggestions besides "run with NSZombies enabled?" And, is this definitely a memory crash?

Comment: On your breakpoints tab, click on the + icon on the lower left, and add an Exception Breakpoint, then run your app and see where it's stopping.

Comment: Already done, and breakpoints are enabled. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know when exactly the app crashes? For example if you are having a crash while returning from a view controller ( deallocating it namely) you may want to check its dealloc method for double releases. Can you give more details?

Comment: I will try to pinpoint when it happens. Up until now it's seemed random, but I will try to verify that.

Comment: @YunusNedimMehel the answer is "it's random." Also, my code is all under ARC.... hmmm. Still investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIGSEGV happens when the code tries to access memory that "doesn't exist" (that is, the address you are trying to use doesn't have a mapping in your virtual address space).

The exact cause of this can be a large number of things - the most common ones are:

- Using pointers that are not (properly) initialized.
- Walking off the end of an array.
- Using memory that has been freed.

Note that all of the above are examples of "undefined behaviour", so you may well have situations where your code doesn't crash although it's doing something wrong, but the same code, under other circumstances, DOES go wrong.

Comment: I would also like to point out that with the "right" kind of badness, you can easily cause a crash in some code that you didn't write. For example, memory allocation and freeing functions often crash if you overwrite the end of an allocated region. Or if you free something that isn't the pointer that you got back when allocating in the first place.

Comment: But this last situation is very unlikely if I'm not using any straight C code at all, right? Which is impossible. Of course I'm using straight C code.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't comment on that. Are you not using any C style arrays at all, anywhere in your code, for example?

Comment: The codebase is huge. There are almost no C-style arrays, but of course there are some. Hmmm... interesting, this situation happens only on the iPad 1, and only in the midst of continuous memory warnings. I temporarily removed the code that responds to the memory warnings, which didn't help.

When running connected to Xcode, no crash report is generated at all. 

So to put it the other way: is it possible that I'm running out of memory, or would that error look different?

Comment: Must confess, I'm not overly familiar with what happens when you run out of memory in IOS. I would expect it to be more like a NULL-pointer exception (which is a SIGSEGV too, but the faulting address would be zero or near zero). Your access is at 0x81093cd0, which appears to be a kernel address according to the name next to it. 

Sorry I can't help more. If it's easy to reproduce the problem, try adding some logging to see where in your code you are, and values of relevant variables.

Comment: Thanks. I was unsubscribing from `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` in my dealloc methods, but I'm convinced that ANY use of this notification for a non-singleton is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a memory-related error (segmentation fault). Keep in mind that `NSZombies` can't catch every memory error.

Comment: when you say "memory-related" the only possibility is that I'm using too much memory, right? And memory that I've given back (that doesn't show in Live Bytes) could not be the problem, right?

Comment: Actually bad access crashes generally refer to something that got released and then you tried to access it somehow

Comment: @Yar nope. It generally means that you're dereferencing an invalid pointer (see Ismael's comment).

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. I'm beginning to suspect that it's part of the brilliant work I do *in response to the memory warns*, which explains why it doesn't happen ever on the iPad 2 (since there are no memory warnings)... okay, I'll dig into this a bit further. Thanks for your answer and the dialogue, very kind.

Comment: As I said in my comment on the other answer, I now think that part of the problem is the use of `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`on any objects that don't live the life of the application. I was dumping the notification in the dealloc, but that might be too late. This is, unfortunately, very hard to prove/demonstrate.